# Responsive website without using Grid

Tags: html, css

I have made a website, it is not responsive. Can I now use Grid for making it resposive and do it from scratch  or there is any other way?

Comment: sure, you can do it with just css(percentage, media queries etc...)

Comment: Thanks, So do i need to give percentage for the height also? @Pepo_rasta

Comment: you can try this to make your website responsive http://stackoverflow.com/a/35605310/5383669

Comment: Thankyou, I have used class wrapper then class headerwrapper, its like nested class. So which class is to be given media query?

Comment: Can you upload a fiddle or an example of your HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

You could still implement Bootstrap if you so wish. You would have to change your width's into bootstrap classes though.

If you use sass / less you can do this:

```
.classItem
  width: 100% (old code)
  @extend .col-md-12 (for less / sass)
```

Or if you have just used css

```
.classItem
  (remove the width in here)

<div class="classItem col-md-12">
  ... content
</div>
```

If you'd rather not use a grid you could use percentages instead.